# Does Zend have validator for greater than 1900

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a date of birth field and want to add a validator so that no one enters a value less than 1900. Does zend have a validator than can be used for this? I see `alnum` but I don't think it's enough because it doesn't set a minimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is `greaterThan` .............

Answer (score 3):

What about [**`Zend_Validate_GreaterThan`**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.greaterthan) ?

*Even if it's said that dates are not supported... Just use 1900 as an integer ;-)*

Answer (score 3):

Your better off using the between validator, and specifying between 1900 and our present year.

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_Between(1900, date('Y'));
```